# to succumb to time/ the time

Tags: definite-article

I would like to use " to succumb to something" in three different but similar context with the word ***time*** and I would like ask in which situations I should use the article ***the***.

Examples :

> She was one of the most beautiful women in the world 50 years ago but
>   has succumbed to (the) time like everybody else.
>
> My grandpa finally has succumbed to (the) time .He has stopped using
>   his rotary dial phone and bought a brand new cell phone.
>
> The school, which was built about 300 years ago, has succumbed to (the)
>   time, most of part of it has collapsed with the last earthquake which
>   cause tremendous effect around the city.

Comment: I don't think your examples reflect natural usages of *time*. They could be written differently but that is not your question. As written, I would go with "the passage of time" or "times". But not "the time" which refers to a specific time (ex. Now is not *the time* to ask such a question).

Comment: @user3169 right

Comment: Yeah, what @user3169 said.  I'd probably go with 1) *ravages of time* 2) *the times* 3) *the passage of time* also in 3.  either *most of it* or *part of it* but not *most of part of it*

Comment: I think people can *succumb to disease*, *succumb to pressure*, *succumb to depression*, *succumb to winter*, *succumb to gravity*. I don't see why we (or even a building) can't *succumb to time*.

Comment: Though if your grandpa is like me, it wasn't time that caused him to trade his land line for a cell, but economics.  $30+ per month for a land line, vs about $7 for the cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Succumb to the time" is wrong since you're not talking about a specific time. If you're talking about someone doing something new, you can use "succumbed to the times":

> My grandpa has finally succumbed to the times. He stopped using his rotary dial phone and bought a brand new cell phone.

"Succumbed to time" sounds odd to me, but a Google search shows that it's popular. When I'm talking about something being damaged over time, I usually say "succumbed to the ravages of time", which is a common idiom. This is especially good for your third example:

> The school, which was built about 300 years ago, has succumbed to the ravages of time. Most parts of it collapsed during the last earthquake, which caused tremendous damage around the city.

For your first example, it might be better to use "age" instead of "time":

> She was one of the most beautiful women in the world 50 years ago, but she has succumbed to age just like everyone else.